# How to fetch a content from other CMS into Magento?

Tags: php, magento, drupal, joomla

I have a Magento site where one of the menu items needs to be a dynamic CMS page from other CMS platform (Joomla or Drupal). The landing page of that menu item (when a user click on it) should list all the news (sorted by date). Then when the user click on one of those articles, the article is opened under the same menu item. I am thinking one of these solutions:

1. Create a module that will retrieve the content data from the CMS database (based on its content/article ID). Would be nice if there is already such a module out there.
2. Use RSS Feed from Joomla/Drupal and show it in the CMS block page of Magento.
3. Use cURL to show a specific URL of Joomla/Drupal menu item link that show the articles.

Which one do you think will be the best solution? Any hint/sample how to achieve that solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a RSS file from your Drupal/Joomla CMS and save it on the server and then just pass the link to the Magento website and just parse the RSS and display it.

Just call the PHTML file in Magento CMS page and put your code to read RSS there.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would create a module - this would be a widget ([Creating a magento widget](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1)). In a widget you can define parameters eg. how many articles to retrieve. In your block file you can do all the server side issues (query the external database). You can create a template to your widget for frontend rendering - this way you can easily adapt the rendering of external content to the actual look of your site.

Probably this solution costs the most in performance, but gives you the most detailed realization.

Eg. you can define a dropdown field in your widget parameters to select a section of cms site:

```
 <parameters>
        <joomla_section type="complex" translate="label">
            <visible>1</visible>
            <required>1</required>
            <label>Section</label>
            <type>select</type>
            <source_model>yourwidget/system_config_source_section</source_model>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        </joomla_section>
```

In the file Yourwidget/Model/System/Config/Source/Section.php you can query the external DB to retrieve available sections, and then in your widget admin popup you can select a section to read articles from.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I will definitely try that. Still considering either as a widget or simply as a block.